# How can i make Glassfish server accept multiple concurrent requests?

Tags: rest, glassfish-4

Am using glassfish 4.1.1 (Windows 7) to host my REST services. I created a simple endpoint that returns a "Hello" string. I then created a client, which sends 50 concurrent requests to perform GET request, but the server only seem to process them 5 at a time. I changed maximum thread pool size to 200, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Here are my complete GlassFish settings

```
http-thread-pool
Max Queue size: -1
Max Thread Pool size 200
Min Thread Pool size 100

Thread-pool-1
Max Queue Size: -1
Max Thread Pool size 200
Min Thread Pool size 50

Network Config->Transports-> tcp
Accepter threads: 4 (I have a 4 core machine)
```

I use fiddler to monitor the requests, which is where I see only 5 requests are sent at a time, once they are complete the next 5 are sent, even though I sent 50 requests simultaneously.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Kay

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, i was re-using the same RestTemplate for the client to make the requests. When I changed my client to use a new RestTemplate for each request, I was able to see that the server got hit with concurrent requests.